# Lock Homw button in Android 6

Tags: android, android-homebutton

all-knowing All!

Till this moment i found answers on my questions simply by searching here - very helpfull resource! But now i can't find answer.
So, i creating a lock screen application, and locking Home button using this solution:
https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker
It's works fine on my 4.1.2 but not works on customer's android 6.
Neither my application noк this Android-HomeKey-Locker alone locks Home button on android 6.

Can anybody say how to solve this on 6 version? ( How it works on android 5 - i don't know - have no such device)

Thanks.

Comment: When i say that it does not work on android 6, i mean that a home button was still active, and shows the desktop.

Comment: does any custom screen-lockers work with android 6 ?

Comment: ok..  i don't know too..